# Hikari Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.getNetworkTimeout()I)

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, hikaricp

I have an error when I create a Hikari connection, in a past have using mysql-connector but finally I decided use hikaricp.

This is the error:

```
[04:17:49] [Server thread/INFO]: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[04:17:49] [Server thread/INFO]: HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
[04:17:49] [Server thread/INFO]: HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
```

My function:

```java
    private static final HikariConfig config;
    private HikariDataSource dataSource;

    static {
        config = new HikariConfig();
    }

    public void open(){ 
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+ database);
        config.setUsername(user);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

I have this pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.divecrafts</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My dedicated server is debian 9 using mariadb (latest version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed modifying my function:

```java
private Connection connection;

public void open(){
        if (checkConnection()) return connection;

        final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mariadb://%s:%s/%s", hostname, port, database));
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);

        connection = ds.getConnection();
        return connection;
}
```

And my pom.xml

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.divecrafts</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

In summary, since I use mariadb I have added mariadb connector.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like a version mismatch issue. The `setNetworkTimeout()` was introduced in `JDBC 4.1` and was not present in `JDBC 4.0`. From your stacktrace , it can be seen that :

```
(com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.getNetworkTimeout()
```

this is what causing the issue. So , I suggest updating the mysql driver and any related dependencies to the latest version possible which should resolve your connection issue.